# how to change an attribute value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am unsure why my code does not work, any help would be much appreciated

> i am trying to create a jquery function where by, when a user clicks on an
>   image (e.g: `messaging-img`) the input field take up the value `101010` | when a user clicks on the `unlimited-img` the input field take up the value `202020`. could one kind;y advise me on this - thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".messaging-img").on("click", function(){
        $("#paypal-ref-111").val("101010");
    });

    $(".unlimited-img").on("click", function(){
        $("#paypal-ref-222").val("202020");
    });
    $(".basic-img").on("click", function(){
        $("#paypal-ref-333").val("303030");
    });
});

<div class="" id="paypal_express_checkout"><input type="" checked="checked"  id="paypal-ref-111" id="paypal-ref-222"  id="paypal-ref-333" value=""/></div>
```

Comment: Multiple `id` attribute, invalid HTML

Comment: You can't give 3 `id` attributes to an element. Decide for one `id`.

Comment: you could change id to class, and in the jquery use `.` instead of `#`, or change the id to just `paypal-ref` and use that for all the selectors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qon5ryps/1/

Comment: @all - Apologies for deleting the answer, however, I believe, people over here has well explained the problem with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

Firstly, I have updated your input field to contain only one ID, named `paypal-ref`. An element can only contain one ID and it must be unique.

```html
<input type="" checked="checked"  id="paypal-ref" value=""/>
```

Secondly, your jQuery has been updated accordingly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".messaging-img").on("click", function() {
    $("#paypal-ref").val("101010");
  });

  $(".unlimited-img").on("click", function() {
    $("#paypal-ref").val("202020");
  });
  $(".basic-img").on("click", function() {
    $("#paypal-ref").val("303030");
  });
});
```

You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nkf2uc10/)